# How can i rewrite this sql using ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a raw sql query here:

```
SELECT
    min(users.updated_at)
FROM
    users
WHERE
    account_id = :account_id
    AND state = 'completed'
    AND amount > 0
    and(
        SELECT
            sum(amount)
        FROM
            users t2
        WHERE
            t2.updated_at <= users.updated_at
            AND t2.account_id = users.account_id
            AND t2.state = 'completed'
            AND t2.amount > 0) > 2000;
```

**Intention of the query is to fetch the date when user has reached the amount of deposit equivalent to 2000.**

I want to rewrite it using Rails's ActiveRecord helpers. My confusion starts with the subquery part. Although i could translate it so far is below:

```
User
  .where(account_id: 5087)
  .where.not(type: EXCLUDED)
  .in_state(*DEPOSIT_STATES)
  .deposits    #amount > 0
  .minimum('updated_at')
  .select("and (select sum(amount) from users t2
    where t2.updated_at <= users.updated_at
      and t2.account_id = users.account_id
      and t2.state = 'completed' and t2.amount > 0) > 2000")
```

**Update**

This query worked but this looks ugly. Any ideas to write it better:

```
User
  .where(account_id: 5087)
  .where.not(type: EXCLUDED)
  .in_state(*DEPOSIT_STATES)
  .deposits
  .where("(select sum(amount) from users t2
    where t2.updated_at <= users.updated_at
      and t2.account_id = users.account_id
      and t2.state = 'completed' and t2.amount > 0) > 2000")
  .minimum('updated_at')
```

Comment: The subquery is not in the SELECT part of the original query, though.

Comment: I am not sure but I think the last statement must be like this: `.where('(select...) > 2000')`

Comment: The problem with this sort of question, IMO, is that it requires potential answerers to have sufficient knowledge of both SQL and ActiveRecord. If you described your desired results and provide example data, then  might get help from people who have expertise in ActiveRecord but not in SQL.

Comment: @kunashir your suggestion worked but then again it looks ugly. Any ideas to write it better ?

Comment: @Ahmadhamza could you add more context about what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @edariedl updated the intention of the query in the question

Comment: Could you also add the database schema and the description what is in the lines of the `users` table? According to your SQL, you go through every user in the account and for every one of those users you will sum all the users with earlier `updated_at` and look whether it is over 2000. So that would mean that every time you make new deposit, new user is created in the account? Also what DB do you use, so we know which set of tools we can use?